# Installing Google App Engine on Ubuntu 2011.04 Natty Narwhal

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get this error when running `dev_appserver.py` just after installing GAE on Ubuntu 2011.04:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 77, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 73, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/nico/p/appengine-python-1.5.3/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 156, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver
  File "/home/nico/p/appengine-python-1.5.3/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 94, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Installing was a bit tricky because GAE only supports Python 2.5:

- Download the [latest Python 2.5.*](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/)
- `./configure --with-zlib` (I also tried without the with-zlib option, same result)
- If you have `/usr/include/sqlite3.h` then remove it because GAE does not compile if present
- make

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.04 comes with python 2.6 as the default version. It is suggested to use Google app engine with version 2.5. I am using it though for many years with python 2.6 without any issues.

What you need to do in order to execute it smoothly with python 2.6 is to edit `google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py` and add these three lines

```
  '_counter',
  '_fastmath',
  'strxor',
```

after `'XOR',` and before `'_Crypto_Cipher__AES',` around line ~1350.

Comment: It worked also with Python 2.7 which is the default for Ubuntu 10.04 Natty Narwhal